# slowing down a php file

Tags: php, ajax

I am testing out an Ajax JQuery script to say please wait while it submits data to a php file. However, to test if the please wait works, is there anyway to make a php file echo some data but return it with a delay?

Comment: Could you show us what you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes: (function [sleep](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php))

```
<?php

$numOfSeconds = 10;
sleep($numOfSeconds);

do_stuff();
```